# Как сделать ограничение на выполнение команды в python

Tags: python

у меня есть программа которая пробегает по списку в exel и смотри существует сайт или нет. При тесте обнаружилось что некоторые сайты которые когда-то существовали могут очень долго грузится и секунд 20 ждать пока не вернёт ответ что сайт не отвечает.Мне нужно что б ожидание ответа небыло дольше 3 сек.
Вот код:

```
import urllib.request
import openpyxl
import time
exit = False
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('base.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
n = (1)
while(exit == False):
    Search = True
    p = 'A' + str(n)
    url = str("http://" + sheet[p].value)
    url2 = str("https://" + sheet[p].value)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        print('Адррес существует')
    except:
        Search = False
    if(Search == False):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen(url2)
            print('Адррес существует')
        except:
            print ('Адреса не существует')
    n += 1
    print(sheet[p].value)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `urlopen(url, timeout=3)`

Comment: неработает. Всё так же долгое ожидание на таких сайтах

Comment: можно пример такой ссылки?

Comment: Вот рабочий: 5.164.31.7 А вот нет: 80.80.201.242

Comment: у меня всё работает с `urlopen(url, timeout=3)` как надо

Comment: Какая у Вас версия Питона и ОС?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import multiprocessing, urllib.request

class MPCheckUrl:
    def __init__(self, timeout=3):
        self.q_in = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.q_out = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.proc: 'multiprocessing.Process' = None
        self.start()
        return

    def check_url(self, url):
        self.q_in.put(url)
        try: return self.q_out.get(timeout=self.timeout)  # timeout 2
        except:
            self.stop()  # остановить проверку, если urlopen завис
            self.start()
            return False

    def stop(self): self.proc.terminate()
    def start(self):
        self.proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run)
        self.proc.daemon = True
        self.proc.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            url = self.q_in.get()
            try: urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=self.timeout)  # timeout 1
            except: self.q_out.put(False)
            else: self.q_out.put(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = [('http://url1', 'http://url2'), ('..', 'http://google.com'), ]
    mp = MPCheckUrl()
    print(['да' if any(map(mp.check_url, links)) else 'нет' for links in urls])
```

['нет', 'да']